# Attributes of objects (REST API) on Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, json, api

I expose my problem. I have created a REST API and now I am using it in an Android APP. The application in question tries to put absences of assistance to students (It is a class project that I am doing in class).

In my application comes a time when choosing a subject and a student enrolled in it, you must select the start time in which you missed class. The way in which I have done it allows me to choose a predefined time, I would like to take the starting hours that is an attribute of an object and put them in a spinner with one of the predefined android adapters (android.R.layout. simple_spinner_item OR android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item).

I have a class AsynkTask, which is responsible for obtaining the Objects of "schedule" from the API, and within those objects are the "Start" attributes of type String that I would like to show in the Spinner.

The thing is that the User-Teacher in question only has to select one of the predefined start times in the Spinner and press the missing button to add the fault. So when selecting a specific time on the spinner should store the "ID" attribute related to the "Start" in question, within a variable to be sent next to the action of the button. (Create the fault works correctly but I have only tried it with a fixed ID).

Here my code

**Activity**

```
public class FaltasActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFaltasReturn, OnAlumnoReturn, OnHorarioReturn {

private TextView nombre, apellidos, correo, titleFault;

private Toolbar toolbar;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private ArrayList<Falta> listaFaltas;
private ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario;
private List<String> list;
private FaltasAdapter adapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;

private Integer idModulo, idAlumno, idHorario;
private Button falta;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_faltas);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_faltas);
    titleFault = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title_fault);
    titleFault.setText("Faltas");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // SPINNER I think the spinner is well implemented ... but I can not add the objects to the lists correctly.
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    listaHorario = new ArrayList<>();
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    HorarioATask horarioATask = new HorarioATask(this, this);
    horarioATask.execute();

    for (int i = 0; i < listaHorario.size(); i++) {
        list.add(listaHorario.get(i).getInicio());
    }

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    //Finish SPINNER code

    idModulo = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID_MODULO");
    idAlumno = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID_ALUMNO");
    idHorario = 1;  //This is the variable to be replaced when a start is selected.

    nombre = findViewById(R.id.item_tittle);
    apellidos = findViewById(R.id.second_item);
    correo = findViewById(R.id.third_item);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvf);

    AlumnoATask alumnoATask = new AlumnoATask(this, this, idAlumno);
    alumnoATask.execute();

    listaHorario = new ArrayList<>();

    falta = findViewById(R.id.action_button_1);
    falta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    final ApiConnector apiConnector = new ApiConnector();
                    final String URI_POST = "faltas";
                    String token;

                    String uri = URI_POST;
                    String method = "POST";
                    String json;

                    Alumno alumno = new Alumno(idAlumno);
                    Modulo modulo = new Modulo(idModulo);
                    Horario horario = new Horario(idHorario);

                    Falta falta = new Falta(alumno, horario, modulo);

                    json = gson.toJson(falta, Falta.class);

                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("userObject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    token = prefs.getString("token", "");

                    apiConnector.consult(uri, method, json, token);

                }
            });
        }
    });

    listaFaltas = new ArrayList<>();

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new FaltasAdapter(this, listaFaltas);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    FaltaATask faltaATask = new FaltaATask(this, this, idAlumno, idModulo);
    faltaATask.execute();

}

@Override
public void onFaltasConsultados(ArrayList<Falta> listaFaltas) {
    this.listaFaltas.clear();
    this.listaFaltas.addAll(listaFaltas);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onFaltasError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error en el listado de faltas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAlumnosConsultados(Alumno alumno) {
    this.nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());
    this.apellidos.setText(alumno.getApellidos());
    this.correo.setText(alumno.getCorreo());
}

@Override
public void onAlumnosError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error en los datos del alumno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//In theory this fills the lists (Interface)
@Override
public void onHorarioConsultados(ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario) {
    this.listaHorario.clear();
    this.listaHorario.addAll(listaHorario);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onHorarioError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error con los horarios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**Model Obbject**

```
public class Horario implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idHorario;
private String inicio;
private String fin;
private Date alta;
private Date baja;

public Horario() {
}

public Horario(Integer idHorario) {
    this.idHorario = idHorario;
}

public Horario(String inicio, String fin, Date alta) {
    this.inicio = inicio;
    this.fin = fin;
    this.alta = alta;
}

public Horario(Integer idHorario, String inicio, String fin, Date alta, Date baja) {
    super();
    this.idHorario = idHorario;
    this.inicio = inicio;
    this.fin = fin;
    this.alta = alta;
    this.baja = baja;
}

public Integer getIdHorario() {
    return this.idHorario;
}

public void setIdHorario(Integer idHorario) {
    this.idHorario = idHorario;
}

public String getInicio() {
    return this.inicio;
}

public void setInicio(String inicio) {
    this.inicio = inicio;
}

public String getFin() {
    return this.fin;
}

public void setFin(String fin) {
    this.fin = fin;
}

public Date getAlta() {
    return this.alta;
}

public void setAlta(Date alta) {
    this.alta = alta;
}

public Date getBaja() {
    return this.baja;
}

public void setBaja(Date baja) {
    this.baja = baja;
}
```

}

**HorarioATask (AsynkTask)**

```
public class HorarioATask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Horario>> {

private Context context;
private OnHorarioReturn mListener;

public HorarioATask(OnHorarioReturn mListener, Context context){
    this.mListener = mListener;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Horario> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    ArrayList<Horario> listaHorarios = new ArrayList<>();

    final String URI_GET = "horarios";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String token;

    String uri;
    String method;
    String json = null;

    final ApiConnector apiConnector = new ApiConnector();

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userObject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    token = prefs.getString("token", "");

    uri = URI_GET;
    method = "GET";

    String response = apiConnector.consult(uri, method, json, token);
    Type tT = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Horario>>() {}.getType();

    if (response.equals("401")){
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
    } else {
        listaHorarios = gson.fromJson(response,tT);
    }

    return listaHorarios;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Horario> listaHorarios) {
    super.onPostExecute(listaHorarios);

    if (listaHorarios == null) {
        mListener.onHorarioError();
    } else {
        mListener.onHorarioConsultados(listaHorarios);
    }
}
```

}

**OnHorarioReturn (Interface)**

```
public interface OnHorarioReturn {

void onHorarioConsultados(ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario);

void onHorarioError();
```

}

I thought it would be something similar to a RecyclerView, but as much as I've tried, I've been unable, it does not show anything.

[View of the activity in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NejwT.jpg)

**activity.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".FaltasActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_faltas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_fault"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/fault_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_tittle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryTextDefaultMaterialLight" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/second_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Apellidos"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryTextDefaultMaterialLight" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/third_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Correo electrónico"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryTextDefaultMaterialLight" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/action_button_1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Falta"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryTextDefaultMaterialDark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your list is empty set and create object of adapted where you get the list

Comment: @VishvaDave Do you mean I have to create an adapter? Can not I use the predefined ones of the Spinner in some way?

Comment: I was meant by this lines for loop and `spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);` should be after filling the list

Comment: tell me where you are getting the data in listaHorario list? add logs and check where it is getting data and let me know

Comment: HorarioATask is in charge of obtaining the data thanks to ApiConnector, the answer is a JSON that are parsened objects are time schedule of the type that is exposed as a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :**

```
public class FaltasActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFaltasReturn, OnAlumnoReturn, OnHorarioReturn {

private TextView nombre, apellidos, correo, titleFault;

private Toolbar toolbar;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private ArrayList<Falta> listaFaltas;
private ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario;
private List<String> list;
private FaltasAdapter adapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;

private Integer idModulo, idAlumno, idHorario;
private Button falta;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_faltas);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_faltas);
    titleFault = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title_fault);
    titleFault.setText("Faltas");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // SPINNER I think the spinner is well implemented ... but I can not add the objects to the lists correctly.
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    listaHorario = new ArrayList<>();
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    HorarioATask horarioATask = new HorarioATask(this, this);
    horarioATask.execute();


    //Finish SPINNER code

    idModulo = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID_MODULO");
    idAlumno = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID_ALUMNO");
    idHorario = 1;  //This is the variable to be replaced when a start is selected.

    nombre = findViewById(R.id.item_tittle);
    apellidos = findViewById(R.id.second_item);
    correo = findViewById(R.id.third_item);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvf);

    AlumnoATask alumnoATask = new AlumnoATask(this, this, idAlumno);
    alumnoATask.execute();

    listaHorario = new ArrayList<>();

    falta = findViewById(R.id.action_button_1);
    falta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    final ApiConnector apiConnector = new ApiConnector();
                    final String URI_POST = "faltas";
                    String token;

                    String uri = URI_POST;
                    String method = "POST";
                    String json;

                    Alumno alumno = new Alumno(idAlumno);
                    Modulo modulo = new Modulo(idModulo);
                    Horario horario = new Horario(idHorario);

                    Falta falta = new Falta(alumno, horario, modulo);

                    json = gson.toJson(falta, Falta.class);

                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("userObject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    token = prefs.getString("token", "");

                    apiConnector.consult(uri, method, json, token);

                }
            });
        }
    });

    listaFaltas = new ArrayList<>();

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new FaltasAdapter(this, listaFaltas);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    FaltaATask faltaATask = new FaltaATask(this, this, idAlumno, idModulo);
    faltaATask.execute();

}

@Override
public void onFaltasConsultados(ArrayList<Falta> listaFaltas) {
    this.listaFaltas.clear();
    this.listaFaltas.addAll(listaFaltas);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     for (int i = 0; i < listaHorario.size(); i++) {
        list.add(listaHorario.get(i).getInicio());
    }

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onFaltasError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error en el listado de faltas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAlumnosConsultados(Alumno alumno) {
    this.nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());
    this.apellidos.setText(alumno.getApellidos());
    this.correo.setText(alumno.getCorreo());
}

@Override
public void onAlumnosError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error en los datos del alumno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//In theory this fills the lists (Interface)
@Override
public void onHorarioConsultados(ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario) {
    this.listaHorario.clear();
    this.listaHorario.addAll(listaHorario);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onHorarioError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error con los horarios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand where the solution is. According to this ... would you fill in the "Horario" when the data in the list is confirmed? Actually, the flaws load correctly, what I do not understand is that the drop-down menu (Spinner) loads the data from the list without using a custom adapter. I have put a screenshot as a guide to what happens to me.

Comment: Effectively I load the string that I want in the Spinner ... But when selecting one of them, how can I make it know which of them was chosen and take the idHorario, to send it when the button is pressed?

Comment: Means is it working now? Spinner is filled by this solution?

Comment: I will explain you full answer but first copy paste it and see the output

Comment: Correct, the Spinner is filled with the correct data. Also, I have understood the error. Simply moving it has been enough. All that's missing is the Spinner selection, I'm looking at it now.

Comment: I imagine that I must add a setOnitemSelectedListener just below setAdapter, right? What I do not understand is the serviceCall part (provinceResponseData.get (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition ()). GetId ());

How am I supposed to get the object ID if I just pass on the name of the object?

Comment: It is getting data from array list where name and id are associated with each other so that from name can get id of it.. Right nlw may be you are using string list so you will get only selected  name.. Yry searching for spinner on click listner... And no need to set listner after adapter.. It can be anywhere in oncreate also possible